# How to disable echo for Arduino hardware serial?

Tags: arduino, serial-port, modem

I'm trying to write serial parser for my Arduino Mega and SIM800L v2.

Here is the simplest code to test:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);   // USB
  Serial2.begin(57600);  // SIM800L 
  Serial2.write("AT+CGMM\r\n");
}

void loop() {
  if(Serial2.available()) {
    Serial.write(Serial2.read());
  }
}
```

Here is the output with modem echo disabled (ATE0):

> AT+CGMM
>
> SIMCOM_SIM800L
>
> OK

And for comparison here is the output with modem echo enabled (ATE1):

> AT+CGMM
>
> AT+CGMM
>
> SIMCOM_SIM800L
>
> OK

So as you can see command is always presented (with modem echo enabled - twice) while **Serial2.read()**

Is there any way to avoid echo command in serial?

I'n understand that this is because echo is on for Arduino Hardware Serial I used. So the core of my question is how to disable echo for Arduino Hardware serial?

**Update:**
I just tested code with SoftwareSerial instead of hardware serial1 - it works as expected - no additional echos... So this confirms that echo somehow should be disabled for Arduino hardware serial. If it's possible...

If I'm using code like this:

```
SoftwareSerial softSerial(12, 13);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);   // USB
  softSerial.begin(57600);  // SIM800L
  softSerial.write("AT+CGMM\r\n");
}

void loop() {
  if(softSerial.available()) {
    Serial.write(softSerial.read());
  }
}
```

The output just like I need:

> SIMCOM_SIM800L
>
> OK

**UPDATE2:**

It seem that this is some hardware issue of my board itself (or board model at all). I'm using RobotDyn ATmega2560+ESP8266 board, not the original Mega or its usual clone.

Comment: I doubt that the command is duplicated by the module with echo enabled. Are you sure that your serial client isn't showing you the command you sent and then the echoed command from the module?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Modem echo for sure disabled with 'ATE0' command. When modem echo enabled I can see two commands (you can see it in output 2) instead of one then it's disabled (output 1).

Comment: Your serial terminal might be also echoing the input.

Comment: Sure, I'm understand it, but I'm not using any terminal for input and watching result.

Comment: *"...but I'm not using any terminal for input and watching result"* -- You mean you're not using a *terminal emulator* program.  In Linux the serial port is accessed as a terminal, hence the device node is e.g.  **/dev/ttyS0** ("tty" is a mnemonic for Teletype terminal).  Since you're skeptical, maybe the only way to prove where the echo(es) is(are) coming from is to put a 'scope probe on the RxD line.

Comment: I understand that echo enabled at Arduino hardware serial, but I don't know of how can I disable it.

Comment: *"I understand that echo enabled at Arduino hardware serial"* -- No, you understand incorrectly; local echo would be performed by the serial terminal driver (i.e. software). UART/USART rarely have local echo capability.  The ATmega SoC on your board certainly does not:   there's no loopback (or echo) capability,  and there's no data path that connects the transmitter to the receiver.  Study the Atmel/Microchip datasheet if you don't believe me.

Comment: It's not a matter of believe. It's matter of fact. Code working fine (no additional echo) if I use SoftwareSerial instead of hardware ports...

Comment: And again - take a look at code - NO any local PC terminal is used to send commands to the modem.

Comment: *"take a look at code"* -- Okay, so where is the code?  Your high-level code isn't salient; you need to locate the kernel code and device driver that actually controls the UART.

Comment: The kernel code and the kernel Arduino UART "device driver" is the part of Arduino project, I can't put it here. And that is why I'm asking here -
 maybe someone know Arduino UART well.

Answer (score 0):

It seem that this is some hardware issue of board I'm using itself (or board model at all). I'm using RobotDyn ATmega2560+ESP8266 board, not the Original Mega or it's usual clone.